# Generally what are the ports that need to be open and remain on a windows server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Normally under windows open and public ports there are nearly 50 to 60 ports. Most of these range between 1 - 1023. Can all those ports keep as it is or should I close them except RDP.

Comment: Only leave open ports for services you require. Close everything else. There's no definitive list that can be codefied in an answer since your requirements will differ from others'.

Comment: That server is probably serving something on some ports. If you close them, you won't be able to use these services.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes, What about windows updates and other critical task like that.

Comment: Like I said, leave open ports for services you require.